# How to create a cubic spline between the lines x=0 and y=1?

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions, cubics, spline

I am trying to create a simple cubic spline from points (0,0) to (m,1) connecting the lines y=1 and x=0.

However, I am having trouble getting the spline to be tangential to the x=0 line at (0,0).

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gbyugajoyi

I presume this means I can't provide the derivative of x=0 to get it to do what I want?

How can I fix this?

I tried using y = vx where "v" is an arbitrarily high constant instead of x=0, and it works, but only at very low "m" values. At higher "m", it switches the spline around to connect the wrong way.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ijyna1uwtf

Is that controllable or fixable either?

Comment: Derivative of x is in a sense, infinity, or undefined, because $y$ changes while $x$ does not

Comment: Yeah I was guessing that. I tried using y=vx instead of x=0 then where I can set v arbitrarily high to simulate the effect I want. It's working sort of, but only at low m values then the spline shifts to connect in the wrong way. Is there any way to improve this so I can go higher on "m"? https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ijyna1uwtf

Comment: Sorry but a spline is not right for this because x=0 has multiple values in the y axis, and thus there is no proper value for the spline at x=0.